# wsgi application is using an older python version

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I have deployed a Pyramid app using mod_wsgi.

I have setup the python path in the virtualhost:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess MyApp user=myUser group=staff threads=4 python-path=/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/env/pyramid.wsgi
```

for debugging purposes, in pyramid.wsgi, I have also put:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
print(sys.version)
```

When I visit the app I can see the app is using python 2.6 instead of 2.7!

The sys.path outputs this:

```
 ['/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', 
'/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.6.egg', 
'/opt/local/lib/python26.zip', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/plat-sunos5', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/lib-old', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

You can see the python 2.6 paths are there, but if I ssh to the server and execute python it launches python2.7.

where does 2.6 come from? which user(apache?) is calling this wsgi app so I can change its python environment?

pls help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using apache with mod_wsgi you should look at using a more relevant webserver for python such as gunicorn.   Gunicorn is written in python and is very fast but most importantly you will be able to easily tell it which python version to run under without compiling/linking different versions.

Its as easy as:

```
pip install gunicorn 
gunicorn --workers=2 /home/myapp/env/pyramid.wsgi:app
```

Answer (score 2):

mod_wsgi doesn't care what version `python` is. It's built against the Python library itself, so if you want it to use a different version then you need to rebuild it.